# Suppress error in xaml using .editorconfig

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, editorconfig, error-suppression

I have following XAML. It's [valid](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12851#issuecomment-730252127) (and code compiles and runs just fine), but VS gives me the error: "*XLS0505 Type 'FontImageSource' is used like a markup extension but does not derive from MarkupExtension*"

```xml
<Image Source="{FontImageSource Color={DynamicResource PrimaryColor}}"/>
```

How can I suppress it in `.editorconfig`? Tried this `dotnet_diagnostic.XLS0505.severity = none`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In XAML there is a special syntax that allows the code to perform additional rules and indirectly set other objects. See the [official Microsoft Docs on Markup Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml-markup-extensions).

So in your case you could set the **FontImageSource** like following

```
<Image >
    <Image.Source>
        <FontImageSource
        FontFamily="{DynamicResource MaterialFontFamily}"
        Glyph="{Binding xxx}"
        Size="44"
        Color="{DynamicResource PrimaryColor}"/>
    </Image.Source>
    
</Image>
```

Comment: That's the point so I use is as markup extension. Member of Xamarin organization suggested that and confirmed that error is invalid: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12851#issuecomment-730252127 And again xaml works just fine. The question is, how to suppress this invalid exception, not how to write xaml so that this exception doesn't occur.